# How to start an activity using AlarmManager etc

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to start code inside an activity at regular intervals using Alarm manager. I have looked at various examples on here but they have not really helped.

For testing purposes, all I am trying to do is pop up a toast at 10 second intervals, but nothing seems to be happening at all. Please help guys!

I have this in the manifest (also declarations for all three activities):

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

Code from main activity, in OnCreate:

```
        //
        // Setting up the Alarm Manager
        //
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class); 
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0,         myIntent, 0); 
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10); 
        long timerInterval = 10 * 1000;  
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), timerInterval, pendingIntent); 
        //finish();
```

AlarmReceiver.java:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    { 
    Toast.makeText(context," onRecieve() test" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class); 
    scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);
    } 
}
```

MyService.java:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate();


 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"test message.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is not showing, because you are calling `startActivity()` on an `Intent` that identifies a `Service`. You should see warnings related to this in LogCat.

I humbly suggest that you use LogCat yourself, via the `Log` class, for logging background operations, rather than attempting to use a `Toast`.

Comment: Thanks! So it's wrong to call startActivity() on an Intent that identifies a Service....hmmm...looks like I'm in for another late night....

Comment: I commented the startActivity() line out but it still won't pop the toast up...:((

Comment: Sorted it - receiver declaration was in the wrong place in the manifest!

Answer (score 0):

test this code:

```
private void establecerAlarmaClick(int when){
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityAlarmita.this, MainActivityAlarmita.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivityAlarmita.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
((AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE)).set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + when * 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```